# 3D transformation for SurfaceView in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I tried to apply some 3D transformation (such as setRotationX) on a surfaceview which is used for camera previewing, but only the frame changes and the content don't.

Answer (score 1):

A SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The Surface is a separate layer that is rendered and composited independently.  The View part is, by default, a transparent rectangle that creates a "hole" in the View layer, so that you can see through the Views to the Surface behind it.

The transformation you mention (`setRotationX()`) is a View method, but the camera preview is sent to the Surface.  That's why the frame changed but the preview itself didn't.

You can send your preview to a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), which can take an arbitrary transformation matrix (`setTransform()`), by using the `Camera.setPreviewTexture()` method.  Or you can send it through a SurfaceTexture to an OpenGL ES texture, which can be rendered on the SurfaceView's Surface, using whatever GLES transformations you want.  For an example of the latter, see [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "texture from Camera" Activity.